# How to delete or remove a Qlabel in PYQT5

Tags: python, user-interface, module, pyqt, pyqt5

Here's the code:

```
from generator import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

def button_clicked(self):
    self.label.setText(make_pass())

def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle('Random password generator')

    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
    self.label.setText('')
    self.label.move(50,50)

    self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
    self.b1.setText('Make password')
    self.b1.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

def update(self):
    self.label.adjustSize()

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

The make_pass() function returns a string, a variable called password.

```
def make_pass():
    for i in range(6):
        n = random.randint(0, 100)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            letters_list.append(random_letter(letters).lower())
        elif n % 2 != 0:
            letters_list.append(random_letter(letters).upper())

    for i in range(3):
        nums_list.append(random_number())

    for i in range(2):
        syms_list.append(random_symbol(syms))

    l = ''.join(letters_list)
    n = ''.join(nums_list)
    s = ''.join(syms_list)

    global password
    password = l, n, s
    password = ''.join(password)
    pass_list = list(password)
    random.shuffle(pass_list)
    password = ''.join(pass_list)

    return password
```

When I run it and press the generate button, it shows a label which is the password. When I run it again, it combines the previous password with the new one and it shows it in a single label.
What I want is that when after I generate a password and then a new one the previous one gets removed and makes space for the new one.

Here's how the problem looks:

[image: strings just add up]

Instead, it should always be one string of 11 characters

Comment: Your code does exactly what you want, since `setText` always replaces the previous text with the new one. The problem is most certainly in the `make_pass()` function, which you should show us. Also note that `update` is a public function that is normally called from the code and should be overridden by also calling the base class `update` implementation, and in your case is completely unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the text and show the make_pass() function

Comment: I assume that those lists (`letters_list`, etc) are global variables. If that's the case, it's pretty obvious: you're constantly appending elements to them each time `make_pass()` is called. Make them local variables of `make_pass()`.

Comment: whats is output of `print(len(password))`?

Comment: @musicamante Thank you so much, it worked, no more long lines and everything's the way I wanted it to be! :) Thanks again.